# Add customer groups in Magento 2 programically

Tags: magento2, patches

Change customer group based on how many orders they've done.
Silver 1-4 orders
Gold 5-6 orders
Emerald >10 orders
You need to add those groups to Magento(programmatically) and ensure that every placed by customer checks if he meets conditions to go into another group. Bear in min that only completed
orders are taken into consideration here, so any customer can be downgraded to the correct tier if it is possible.
This should be created using a patch.

Comment: ok.. **it's not really clear what you are asking for**. how to create the customer groups programmatically? or how to move a customer from one group to another based on number of placed orders?

Comment: I have no idea how to move a customer from one group to another based on number of placed orders? and this move should also work so that the customer can be moved to the weaker group, for example from group gold to silver, I'm hoping that this explanation is clearer :)

Comment: yeah, it's clearer, but what you asking for is a complete module :)

Comment: Yes, but I do not want a complete module, I just want to know how to assign customer groups according to the number of orders, because I have already created new groups myself.:)

Comment: check my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an observer on the `checkout_submit_all_after` event in the `etc/webapi_rest/events.xml` file.

In the observer class you should inject the following classes and initialize private properties in the constructor

```
Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface to be stored inside $this->customer
Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory to be stored inside $this->salesOrderCollection
```

then, in the `execute()` method of your observer, retrieve the order:

```
$order = $observer->getData('order');
```

then load the customer:

```
$customer = $this->customer->getById($order->getBillingAddress()->getCustomerId());
```

then count the orders of the customers:

```
$collection = $this->salesOrderCollection->create();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getCustomerId());
count($collection)
```

make your decisions based on your logic and then assign the customer group to the customer entity:

```
$groupId=6; //replace with your actual group ID
$customer->setGroupId($groupId);
$customer->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

1)create InstallData file in module setup folder with following code:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    protected $groupFactory;

    public function __construct(GroupFactory $groupFactory) {
        $this->groupFactory = $groupFactory;
    }

    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $group = $this->groupFactory->create();
        $group
            ->setCode('New Group')
            ->setTaxClassId(3) 
            ->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```